# Yii AR: how to select selected values count?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have SQL query that return unique values and how many times this value is in DB.

```
SELECT sl_keyword, COUNT(sl_keyword)
FROM search_log
GROUP BY sl_keyword
```

How can I do same using active record in Yii? This code works, but not return count. Only keyword and language:

```
$criteria            = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select    = 'sl_keyword, sl_language, COUNT(sl_keyword) as times';
$criteria->condition = 'sl_datetime >= :date_from AND sl_datetime <= :date_to';
$criteria->group     = 'sl_keyword, sl_language';
$criteria->offset    = $offset;
$criteria->limit     = $itemsPerPage;
$criteria->params    = array(':date_from' => $dateFrom, ':date_to' => $dateTo);
$result              = self::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: put the code where you try to  use count

Comment: where you are using $result array?

Comment: use `Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll()` instead of AR

Answer (score 0):

try like this (im assuming you are using foreach loop)

```
foreach($result as $r)
{
   $times =  $r['times'];  // get like this
   $sl_keyword =  $r['sl_keyword'];
   $sl_language =  $r['sl_language'];
}
```